# What would happen if we provide to OP_CHECKMULTISIG more than threshold number (m) of signatures?

Tags: script, multi-signature

Asked [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/34001/multisignature-what-happens-if-the-number-of-signatures-exceeds-the-threshold) but still no answer.

What would happen if we provide to OP_CHECKMULTISIG opcode more than threshold number (m) of signatures?

For example, if the `m = 3` and `n = 6` and the output script is:

```
3 <pubkey_1> ... <pubkey_6> 6 CHECKMULTISIG
```

And we provide, for example, this input script (or witness stack for segWit 0):

```
0 <signature_1> <signature_2> <signature_3> <signature_4> <signature_5>
```

Will it pass or fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the activation of BIP147 (nulldummy softfork) in 2017, the answer is **no**, this will fail. Before that point it would have been generally non-standard but allowed.

An input to `OP_CHECKMULISIG` expects on the stack: (from back to front):

- the number *n*
- *n* public keys
- the number *k*
- *k* signatures
- a dummy element (ignored pre-BIP147, must be 0 post-BIP147)

In your example, n=6 is read, followed by 6 keys, then k=3, and then 3 signatures. These 3 signatures *do* match the penultimate 3 keys, which on itself would work. However, after that a 0 is expected, yet instead there is another signature, which fails.

Before BIP147, the signature_2 would function as the dummy, and signature_1, plus a 1 (from the evaluation of `OP_CHECKMULTISIG`) and 0 would be left on the stack.

Comment: Actually I provided just 5 signatures (not 6) and the last one is signature_5 (not signature_6). Thus, (before BIP147) signature_3, signature_4 and signature_5 would be taken by the OP_CHECKMULTISIG, signature_2 is dummy (instead of zero), signature_1 plus 1 (as a result of OP_CHECKMULTISIG) would left on the stack. Also zero would left on the stack. Is that more correct or I missed something?

Comment: @MudjaAdjum That sounds right.